# What are the rules of closing file descriptors after calling dup/dup2?

Tags: c, io, file-descriptor

I feel like this is a topic I've taken for granted. In the past I literally just closed as many file descriptors "because I was told to". Most of the time this worked, but occasionally I ran into some unpredictable behaviour.

Thus, I'd like to ask - what the rule for closing file descriptors after calling dup / dup2?

Let's say I want to perform `cat < in > out`.

```
fd[IN] = open("in", O_RDONLY);
saved_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
dup2(fd[IN], STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd[IN])

fd[OUT] = open("out", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd[OUT], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fd[OUT])


// Later on when I want to restore stdin and stdout
dup2(saved_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);
close(saved_stdin);
dup2(saved_stdout, STDINOUT_FILENO);
close(saved_stdout);
```

Is this correct or should I be closing more file descriptors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is indeed quite simple. For both `dup()` variants, it is true, that:

- The source fd remains open and will have to be closed once it is no longer needed.
- The target file descriptor,

  - when using `dup()`, is always an unused one
  - when using `dup2()`, is implicitly closed and replaced by a copy of the source fd.
- The new target fd has to be closed, when it is no longer needed.

*Source fd refers to the file descriptor to be duplicated, while target fd is the new file descriptor.*

```
int new_fd = dup(source_fd);
dup2(source_fd, new_fd);
```

So yes, your code does the necessary closes, and no unneeded ones.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify what you mean by source fd and target fd?

Comment: i've a last question - is there any harm in saving stdin/stdout multiple times in a row? e.g. `saved_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO)`. If i'm correct this neither closes `saved_stdin` nor `STDIN_FILENO` am I correct?

Comment: This is correct, but the following ` dup2()` closes the previous stdin and replaces it with fd[IN]. That's no problem at all.

Comment: I was wondering though, if you do `saved_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO)` followed by `dup2(fd[IN], STDIN_FILENO)`. Now STDIN_FILENO points to `fd[IN]`. Then if you call `saved_stdin = dup(STDIN_FILENO)` again wouldn't that replace `saved_stdin` (which holds original `STDIN_FILENO`) with `fd[IN]`? I feel like I'm overthinking this or something

Comment: @doctopus You may not confuse the overwriting of a _variable_ with the overwriting of a _file descriptor_. Setting a variable does of course not have any side effec on the set of file descriptors associated with a process.

Answer (score 0):

The figures is come from CSAPP System-Level:

[Figure 2: Before Redirect IO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lt4P.png)

```
dup2(4,1);
```

[Figure 1: After Redirect IO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zolec.png)

Notice the `refcnt` of `fd 1` has changed to 0, after call dup2.

According to the description of `close` in [linux manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html). It said:

> if the file descriptor was the last reference to a file which has been removed using unlink(2), the file is deleted.

`close` be used to decrease the refcnt of opened file. we use `dup` to create a new fd will increase the refcnt of opened file. when we call `close` function, it did't close the file immediately, it only decrease the reference count of file. the file will be close/delete when the refcnt is 0.

So it's really like the Reference counting for memory management.